# How to code a flutter function which runs if and only changes detected?

Tags: flutter

I'm doing an app in flutter which has 3 flat buttons able to set values(1-3) when they pressed. Now I need a function that can print some message according to the values it received.

```
value == 3 ? print("happy") : print("press any button");
value == 2 ? print("normal") : print("press any button");
value == 1 ? print("worst") : print("press any button");
```

NOTE: onpressed function of each button can only set values. The function to detect change must be run independently somewhere which is not returning any widgets inside it. Simply onChanged() function for a group of buttons.

For reference:

```
Widget flatbuttongrop(){
return Form(
child: Row(
  children: <Widget>[
     FlatButton(
            shape: CircleBorder(),
            color: Colors.red,
            child: Text("H"),
            onPressed: () {
             value = 1;
              //  return value = 1;
            },
          ),

           FlatButton(
            shape: CircleBorder(),
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: Text("N"),
            onPressed: (){
            //  return value = 2;
            value = 2;
            },
          ),

           FlatButton(
            shape: CircleBorder(),
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Text("S"),
            onPressed: (){
              value = 3;
            },
          ),
  ],

),
onChanged: ()
{
  //If any flatbutton pressed then it must indicate here.
},
  );

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have to do it inside `onPressed` callback

Comment: Thanks for the consideration. onPressed of each button is only for setting value. Kindly please look at my NOTE @pskink

Comment: there is no way to detect somewhere if `int` value changed from 1 to 2 - you have to do it in flat button callback (or change `int` into some [Listenable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/Listenable-class.html) value)

Comment: https://youtu.be/s-ZG-jS5QHQ

Comment: @TedHenry I don't want a widget builder. What I'm trying to make was simply like form validation . But instead of text fields, I need to validate the button was pressed and need to update the onchanged of the form widget. Not validating the TextField just validating that button was pressed and update onChange function of form widget. I'm a newbie to Flutter.

Comment: Have you tried `setState`?

Comment: @TedHenry Yes I tried but it didn't work async with the value changes also tried some Future functions and await methods.

Comment: Post a short, complete app that shows what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume you are using Stateful Widget if yes, following below steps will solve your problem

You could use the String function for that

```
String getStringValue(int value){
  if(value == 1)
   return "Worst"
  else if(value == 2)
   return "Normal"
  else if(value == 3)
   return "Happy"
  else
   return "Press Any Button"
}
```

And in the onPressed you could update your code like this

```
onPressed: (){
  setState((){
    value = someIntValue;
  });
}
```

And wherever you need to use that String just call

```
getStringValue(someIntValue)
```

Comment: The problem was simple I'm using Flatbuttons inside Form widget (reference code) instead of textformfileds / textfields. Form widget have onchanged function. How can I use the onchange function if any of a button inside the form widget pressed?

Comment: what exactly you want to change in the onChange function ?

Comment: Navigating to a new page.

Comment: the onChange is the callback function for the Form widget so it will be called whenever a widget is changing its state inside the Form Widget sub tree, so it cannot be used that way instead you should use that in the onPressed callback of the FlatButton widget

Comment: Can you suggest me any way to detect changes in a  button group and able to route to a new screen. I don't want  to run the validation function inside each and every onpressed